# Dynamic observation space (with Box) in OpenAI environment

Tags: dynamic, space, openai-gym

Is there a way to define an observation space (Box) that changes at each step? For example, at first it would be like shape=(80,2), at the next iteration (79,2), and so on. In other words, my observation is a 2D array, where at each iteration, I want to remove one row of the array.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you keep the observation space to be constant and append zeros to your state? In your case, you can keep it constant at shape=(80,2)

Comment: I have already tried setting with zero, but it does affect the training of the agent, since the action in my setting is to select an index of the observation. After a while, the actions are unique, showing the states set with zero, like this;

actions= [13, 23, 9, 31, 5, 23, 12, 15, 12, 30, 19, 9, 0, 28, 16, 22, 28, 3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5].  is there another way to make the observation dynamic? Thank you!

Comment: If you have a variable observation space, how are you feeding it into a neural network?

Comment: I am using stable_baselines framework, and I do not know how the framework feeds  the variable observation space

Comment: Can you print the shape of the states?

Comment: Do you mean the shape of a dynamic observation state? If so, I do not know how to do it; that is my question of how I can have a dynamic observation space. In my case, I want to be able to remove or add a row(s) of the observation state at each iteration.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your code as well as the environment?

Comment: You can pad zero to observation space, and apply action masking to action space to filter out invalid actions.